# disable logging of a service to journald altogether

Tags: service, systemd, systemd-journald

I have a service which logs unnecessary messages to journald.
Can this be switched off completely?

I tried to get it done with log4j.properties that belongs to the service, but that did not help
Regards Hans

Answer (score 3):

`StandardOutput` and `StandardError` is connected to the journal by default. But you can customize this in your `[Service]` section and redirect both to `/dev/null`:

```
[Service]
...
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null
```

Comment: Using the command `sudo systemctl edit servicename` will automatically create an override file for the service, allowing you to make these changes while keeping the original file intact.